# How to filter with distinct+count condition on relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables with 1 having ForeignKey to the others:

```
class Audio(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    annotations = db.relationship('Annotation', backref='audio', lazy='dynamic')
    # ...

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    annotations = db.relationship('Annotation', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')
    # ...

class Annotation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    audio_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('audio.id'), nullable=False)
    user_id  = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

How can I get all the Audio entries such that for the subset S of Annotations having Annotation.audio_id==Audio.id we also have S.distinct(Annotation.user_id) < N ?

Answer (score 0):

That works:

```
q = db.session.query(Annotation.audio_id, db.func.count(Annotation.user_id.distinct()).label('count')).group_by(Annotation.audio_id).subquery()
results = db.session.query(Audio).join(q, q.c.audio_id == Audio.id).filter(q.c.count<2).all()
```